# Get dates for last quarter and this quarter through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a report that needs to get the dates for last quarter and this quarter through Javascript. The code worked last month but in March it doesn't work. It shows last quarter as this quarter and this quarter shows as next quarter. I am using datejs in this project. Here is the code I am using:

```
function thisQuarterDates(from, to) {
    var month = Date.parse('today').toString('MM');
    var quarterMonth = (Math.floor(month/3)*3)+1;
    var year = Date.parse('today').toString('yyyy');

    var quarterStartDate = (quarterMonth < 10) ? quarterMonth+'/1/' +year : quarterMonth+'/1/'+ year;
    var quarterEndDate = Date.parse(quarterStartDate).add(2).months().moveToLastDayOfMonth().toString('M/d/yyyy');
    var today = Date.parse('today').toString('M/d/yyyy');

    document.getElementById(from).value = quarterStartDate;
    document.getElementById(to).value = quarterEndDate;
}


function lastQuarterDates(from, to) {
    var month = Date.parse('today').toString('MM');
    var quarter = (Math.floor(month/3))+1;
    var lastQuarter = (quarter > 1) ? quarter - 1 : lastQuarter = 4;
    var year;
    if (((((lastQuarter-1)*3)+1) < 10))
    {
        year = Date.parse('today').toString('yyyy');
    }
    else
    {
        year = Date.parse('today').add(-1).years().toString('yyyy');
    }
    var firstDate = ((((lastQuarter-1)*3)+1) < 10) ? (((lastQuarter-1)*3)+1) +'/1/'+ year : (((lastQuarter-1)*3)+1) +'/1/'+ year;
    var lastDate = Date.parse(firstDate).add(2).months().moveToLastDayOfMonth().toString('M/d/yyyy');

    document.getElementById(from).value = firstDate;
    document.getElementById(to).value = lastDate;
}
```

Anyone know why it's incorrect or is there an easier way?

Comment: What library are you using for prototypes of Date, such as moveToLastDayOfMonth()? Is it your custom code?

Comment: At the time I wrote this I was using [dateJS](http://www.datejs.com/), however, I have since switched to [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). DateJS hasn't been maintained in quite some time. MomentJS is maintained and it works the same with some additional features.

Comment: May this will help you . http://stackoverflow.com/a/20989200/2837412

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the first function change

```
var quarterMonth = (Math.floor(month/3)*3)+1;
```

with

```
var quarterMonth = (Math.floor((month-1)/3)*3)+1;
```

and on the second function

```
var quarter = (Math.floor(month/3))+1;
```

with

```
var quarter = (Math.floor((month-1)/3))+1;
```

and I think it will be fine.

And on the second function I don't see the point of

```
((((lastQuarter-1)*3)+1) < 10)
```

a simple

```
(lastQuarter < 4)
```

will do the same job

Answer (score 18):

Simple generic solution in pure JS. 
First calculate **quarter number**:

```
const today = new Date();
const quarter = Math.floor((today.getMonth() / 3));
```

Next, **current quarter**:

```
const startFullQuarter = new Date(today.getFullYear(), quarter * 3, 1);
const endFullQuarter = new Date(startFullQuarter.getFullYear(), startFullQuarter.getMonth() + 3, 0);
```

**Previous quarter**

```
const startFullQuarter = new Date(today.getFullYear(), quarter * 3 - 3, 1);
const endFullQuarter = new Date(startFullQuarter.getFullYear(), startFullQuarter.getMonth() + 3, 0);
```

Add or subtract `3's` per quarter in expression `new Date(today.getFullYear(), quarter * 3 - x, 1)` to get future or past quarters.

Comment: You should use `Math.ceil()`. Because if you got the current month of may (5), then you'll receive `1` as quarter

Comment: @dewey Quarter number calculation is needed in following calculations, it is not direct quarter number like Q1, etc. If you use `quarter` variable in `startFullQuarter` calculation it yields `Fri Apr 01 2022 00:00:00` which is proper result.

Comment: To get quarter number you are using "today" before it is defined. The order of the two lines should be reversed.

Comment: You need to use `Math.floor()` to get the months to group correctly.  If you want a proper quarter number that is 1 indexed rather than 0 indexed, just add 1 to it at the end.

Answer (score 11):

if you're using moment.js this might be easier:

```
var quarterAdjustment= (moment().month() % 3) + 1;
var lastQuarterEndDate = moment().subtract({ months: quarterAdjustment }).endOf('month');
var lastQuarterStartDate = lastQuarterEndDate.clone().subtract({ months: 3 }).startOf('month');
```

conversion to date.js should be fairly easy.

Comment: Awesome snippet, but I noticed that to get the first day of the quarter, a slight modification was needed - changed startOf('month') to endOf('month') and added a day:  var lastQuarterStartDate = lastQuarterEnd.clone().subtract(3, 'months').endOf('month').add(1,'days')

Comment: ah, good catch. I guess you could also do: var lastQuarterStartDate = lastQuarterEndDate.clone().subtract({ months: 2 }).startOf('month');

Comment: How about simply
```const endOfLasQuarter = moment().date(1).subtract(1, 'quarter').endOf('quarter')```

Answer (score 6):

Using **moment.js library** its very simple to get the start and end date of a particular quarter as follows:

```
Start date of last quarter = moment().subtract(lastQuarterNumber, 'quarter').startOf('quarter');

End date of last quarter = moment().subtract(lastQuarterNumber, 'quarter').endOf('quarter');

Start date of current quarter = moment().startOf('quarter');

End date of current quarter = moment().endOf('quarter');
```

Comment: Shouldn't the end date of the last quarter be:
`End date of last quarter = moment().subtract(lastQuarterNumber, 'quarter').endOf('quarter');`

Comment: Is there a way to to get Quarter To Date (QTD)?

Answer (score 4):

I have been using **date-fns** library for some time now. The methods it exposes can be immensely useful in solving such problems.

You can make use of `addQuarter` and `subQuarter` methods.

Code would look something like:

```
    const lastQuarterStartDate = startOfQuarter(subQuarters(new Date(2014, 8, 1),1))

    const lastQuarterEndDate = lastDayOfQuarter(subQuarters(new Date(2014, 8, 1),1))

    const thisQuarterStartDate = startOfQuarter(new Date(2014, 8, 1))

    const thisQuarterEndDate = lastDayOfQuarter(new Date(2014, 8, 1))
```

Reference: https://date-fns.org/v2.21.2/docs/addQuarters

Answer (score 3):

Using **moment.js**:

- This quarter START: `moment().startOf('quarter')`
- This quarter END: `moment().endOf('quarter')`
- Previous quarter START: `moment().subtract(1, 'quarter').startOf('quarter')`
- Previous quarter END: `moment().subtract(1, 'quarter').endOf('quarter')`
- Next quarter START: `moment().add(1, 'quarter').startOf('quarter')`
- Next quarter End: `moment().add(1, 'quarter').endOf('quarter')`

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code to get all quarter based on january and april

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishchit14/a8LMn/)</kbd>

**Code :**

```
 // startMonth should be january or april

  function setQuarter(startMonth) {
    var obj = {};
    if(startMonth=='january'){

        obj.quarter1 = {start:moment().month(0).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(2).endOf('month')}
        obj.quarter2 = {start:moment().month(3).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(5).endOf('month')}
        obj.quarter3 = {start:moment().month(6).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(8).endOf('month')}
        obj.quarter4 = {start:moment().month(9).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(11).endOf('month')}
        console.log(obj);
        return obj;
    }
    else if(startMonth=='april'){

        obj.quarter1 = {start:moment().month(3).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(5).endOf('month')}
        obj.quarter2 = {start:moment().month(6).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(8).endOf('month')}
        obj.quarter3 = {start:moment().month(9).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(11).endOf('month')}
        obj.quarter4 = {start:moment().month(0).startOf('month').add('years',1),end:moment().month(2).endOf('month').add('years',1)}
        console.log(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}

 setQuarter('april');
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishchit14/a8LMn/)</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

Using this we can get Quarter's start and end dates dynamically irrespective of start of the financial year(Quarter).

```js
var fYearStart=new Date('2021-1-29') //Pass your financial year's start date
var q1Start=new Date(fYearStart.getFullYear(),fYearStart.getMonth(),1)
var dummy1=new Date(fYearStart.getFullYear(),fYearStart.getMonth(),1)
var dummy5=new Date(fYearStart.getFullYear(),fYearStart.getMonth(),1)
var q1End=new Date(dummy1.setMonth(dummy1.getMonth()+3))
var q1FinalEnd=new Date(dummy5.setMonth(dummy5.getMonth()+3))
q1FinalEnd.setSeconds(q1End.getSeconds()-1)
console.log(q1Start.toLocaleString())
console.log(q1FinalEnd.toLocaleString())
var q2Start=new Date(q1End.getFullYear(),q1End.getMonth(),1)
var dummy2=new Date(q1End.getFullYear(),q1End.getMonth(),1)
var dummy6=new Date(q1End.getFullYear(),q1End.getMonth(),1)
var q2End=new Date(dummy2.setMonth(dummy2.getMonth()+3))
var q2FinalEnd=new Date(dummy6.setMonth(dummy6.getMonth()+3))
q2FinalEnd.setSeconds(q2End.getSeconds()-1)
console.log(q2Start.toLocaleString())
console.log(q2FinalEnd.toLocaleString())
var q3Start=new Date(q2End.getFullYear(),q2End.getMonth(),1)
var dummy3=new Date(q2End.getFullYear(),q2End.getMonth(),1)
var dummy7=new Date(q2End.getFullYear(),q2End.getMonth(),1)
var q3End=new Date(dummy3.setMonth(dummy3.getMonth()+3))
var q3FinalEnd=new Date(dummy7.setMonth(dummy7.getMonth()+3))
q3FinalEnd.setSeconds(q3End.getSeconds()-1)
console.log(q3Start.toLocaleString())
console.log(q3FinalEnd.toLocaleString())
var q4Start=new Date(q3End.getFullYear(),q3End.getMonth(),1)
var dummy4=new Date(q3End.getFullYear(),q3End.getMonth(),1)
var dummy8=new Date(q3End.getFullYear(),q3End.getMonth(),1)
var q4End=new Date(dummy4.setMonth(dummy4.getMonth()+3))
var q4FinalEnd=new Date(dummy8.setMonth(dummy8.getMonth()+3))
q4FinalEnd.setSeconds(q4End.getSeconds()-1)
console.log(q4Start.toLocaleString())
console.log(q4FinalEnd.toLocaleString())
```