# In Moment.js, how do you get the current financial Quarter?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Is there a simple/built in way of figuring out the current financial quarter?

ex:

- Jan-Mar: 1st
- Apr-Jul: 2nd
- Jul-Sept: 3rd
- Oct-Dec: 4th

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is now supported in moment:

```
moment('2014-12-01').utc().quarter() //outputs 4
moment().quarter(); //outputs current quarter ie. 2
```

[Documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/quarter/)

Comment: For those looking to get the actual dates: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14927736

Comment: how about quarter for a year that starts in july

Comment: Moment is freaking amazing

Answer (score 20):

Using version 2.14.1+ you can do something like the following:

`moment().quarter()` returns the current quarter number: 1, 2, 3, 4.

```
moment().quarter(moment().quarter()).startOf('quarter');
```

Would return the current quarter with the date set to the quarter starting date.

```
moment().quarter(moment().quarter()).startOf('quarter');
```

Would return the current quarter with the date set to quarter ending date.

You could also define a function that takes the corresponding quarter number as argument (1,2,3,4), and returns an object containing the start and end date of the quarter.

```
function getQuarterRange(quarter) {

  const start = moment().quarter(quarter).startOf('quarter');

  const end = moment().quarter(quarter).endOf('quarter');

  return {start, end};
}
```

Comment: There's no need to pass in the current quarter number when working with the current date.  In other words, these two statements are identical:

`moment().quarter(moment().quarter()).startOf('quarter');`
`moment().startOf('quarter');`

Answer (score 6):

Use this simple code to get all quarter based on january and april

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishchit14/a8LMn/)

**Code :**

```
 // startMonth should be january or april

  function setQuarter(startMonth) {
    var obj = {};
    if(startMonth=='january'){

        obj.quarter1 = {start:moment().month(0).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(2).endOf('month')}
        obj.quarter2 = {start:moment().month(3).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(5).endOf('month')}
        obj.quarter3 = {start:moment().month(6).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(8).endOf('month')}
        obj.quarter4 = {start:moment().month(9).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(11).endOf('month')}
        console.log(obj);
        return obj;
    }
    else if(startMonth=='april'){

        obj.quarter1 = {start:moment().month(3).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(5).endOf('month')}
        obj.quarter2 = {start:moment().month(6).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(8).endOf('month')}
        obj.quarter3 = {start:moment().month(9).startOf('month'),end:moment().month(11).endOf('month')}
        obj.quarter4 = {start:moment().month(0).startOf('month').add('years',1),end:moment().month(2).endOf('month').add('years',1)}
        console.log(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}

 setQuarter('april');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishchit14/a8LMn/)

Answer (score 6):

**START DATE**

```
moment().quarter(moment().quarter()).startOf('quarter');
```

Would return the current quarter with the date set to the quarter starting date.

```
moment("2019", "YYYY").quarter(4).startOf('quarter');
```

Would return the starting date of the 4th quarter of the year "2019".

```
moment().startOf('quarter');
```

Would return the starting date of the current quarter of current year.

**END DATE**

```
moment().quarter(moment().quarter()).endOf('quarter');
```

Would return the current quarter with the date set to quarter ending date.

```
moment("2019", "YYYY").quarter(4).endOf('quarter');
```

Would return the ending date of the 4th quarter of the year "2019".

```
moment().endOf('quarter');
```

Would return the ending date of the current quarter of current year.

Answer (score 4):

I dont think any of these answers explain how to get the financial quarter. They explain how to get the calendar quarter.

I do not have a clean answer as thats what led me here. But the fiscal quarter is what is really wanted. And that is based on the start month of the fiscal year.

For example if my company's fiscal start month is February. Then at the time of writing this January 9th 2017 I'm actually in Q4 2016.

To accomplish this we need a way to get the quarter relative to a supplied integer of the start month.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built in right now, but there is conversation to add formatting tokens for quarters. https://github.com/timrwood/moment/pull/540

In the meantime, you could use something like the following.

```
Math.floor(moment().month() / 3) + 1;
```

Or, if you want it on the moment prototype, do this.

```
moment.fn.quarter = function () {
    return Math.floor(this.month() / 3) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Hmm...according to that we are in the 3rd quarter now: floor(11/4) + 1

Comment: I was looking at https://github.com/adjohnson916/moment/commit/3540e180589c010eedbe604707f794b59c77ef86 and it used the formula `return ~~((this.month()) / 3) + 1;`. What does ~~ mean? EDIT: Nvm figured out it's FLOOR.

Comment: Ah yes, that should be `month / 3`.

Comment: `~` is a bitwise NOT operator that is sometimes used instead of flooring. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 2):

The formula that seems to work for me is:

```
Math.ceil((moment().month() + 1) / 3);
```

moment().month() gives back the 0-11 month format so we have to add one

```
THE ACTUAL MONTH = (moment().month() + 1)
```

then we have to divide by 3 since there are 3 months in a quarter.

```
HOW MANY QUARTERS PASSED = (THE ACTUAL MONTH) / 3
```

and then we have to get the ceiling of that (round to the nearest quarter end)

```
CEILING(HOW MANY QUARTERS PASSED)
```

EDIT:

The [Official formula](https://github.com/adjohnson916/moment/commit/3540e180589c010eedbe604707f794b59c77ef86) (not commited yet) is:

```
~~((this.month()) / 3) + 1;
```

which means `Math.floor((this.month()) / 3) + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

The simplist way to do this is

```
Math.floor(moment.month() / 3)
```

That will give you the zero based quarter index. ie 0, 1, 2, or 3.

Then, if you want the quarter's literal number, just add one.

Comment: That is now how the quarter is determined

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by [Nishchit Dhanani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2837412/nishchit-dhanani), is correct but has one issue in 'April' scenario.

Issue: If your financial year is April than, For first 3 months i.e. JAN, FEB & MAR

```
obj.quarter1.start date returns, 1-April-CurrentYear [incorrect Value]
obj.quarter4.end date retunrs, 31-March-NextYear [incorrect Value]
```

Correct values should be,

```
Start = 1-April-PreviuosYear
End = 31-March-CurrentYear
```

So, Taking consideration for first 3 month it can be written something like,

```
    const obj = {};

/* 0-Jan, 1-Feb, 2-Mar */
    if (moment().month() <= 2) { 
        obj.quarter1 = { start: moment().month(3).startOf('month').add('years', -1), end: moment().month(5).endOf('month').add('years', -1) };
        obj.quarter2 = { start: moment().month(6).startOf('month').add('years', -1), end: moment().month(8).endOf('month').add('years', -1) };
        obj.quarter3 = { start: moment().month(9).startOf('month').add('years', -1), end: moment().month(11).endOf('month').add('years', -1) };
        obj.quarter4 = { start: moment().month(0).startOf('month'), end: moment().month(2).endOf('month') };    
    } else {
        obj.quarter1 = { start: moment().month(3).startOf('month'), end: moment().month(5).endOf('month') };
        obj.quarter2 = { start: moment().month(6).startOf('month'), end: moment().month(8).endOf('month') };
        obj.quarter3 = { start: moment().month(9).startOf('month'), end: moment().month(11).endOf('month') };
        obj.quarter4 = { start: moment().month(0).startOf('month').add('years', 1), end: moment().month(2).endOf('month').add('years', 1) };    
    }
    console.log(obj);
```