# Getting the last day of a date's current quarter using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a javascript date such as 05-04-2020.

I am trying to figure out how to get the current quarter of that date and then the last day of that quarter. The answer in this case should be 06-30-2020.

Below is a function that I created, but have a feeling it isn't the best way to do it:

```
function getLastDayOfQuarterMonth(date) {
    let retVal
    const quarter = moment(date).quarter()
    switch(quarter) {
      case 1:
        retVal = new Date(moment(date).year(), 2, 31)
        break;
      case 2:
        retVal = new Date(moment(date).year(), 5, 30)
        break;
      case 3:
        retVal = new Date(moment(date).year(), 8, 30)
        break;
      case 4:
        retVal = new Date(moment(date).year(), 11, 31)
        break;
    }

    return retVal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [endOf](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) function for that.

Example :

```
function getLastDayOfQuarterMonth(date) {
    let retVal = moment().quarter(moment(date).quarter()).endOf('quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
    return retVal
}
let date = "05-04-2020";
alert(getLastDayOfQuarterMonth(date));
```

JSFiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gt7kexL4/)

Main [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40412192/2385565)

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of [`quarter`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/quarter/) and [`endOf`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) methods provided by `moments`.

```js
const date = "05-04-2020";

const getLastDayOfTheQuarter = (date) => moment().quarter(moment(date, "MM-DD-YYYY").quarter()).endOf('quarter').format("MM-DD-YYYY");

console.log(getLastDayOfTheQuarter(date));
console.log(getLastDayOfTheQuarter(moment().format("MM-DD-YYYY")));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

For simplicity, I have considered the input and output format as `MM-DD-YYYY`. It can be updated as per the need.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use [`endOf("quarter")`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/):

```js
function getLastDayOfQuarterMonth(date) {
  return moment(date, "MM-DD-YYYY").endOf('quarter').toDate();
}
console.log(getLastDayOfQuarterMonth("05-04-2020"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Please note that you have to specify format to correctly parse `05-04-2020` in moment, see [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). You can use [`toDate()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) to get a copy of the native Date object that Moment.js wraps or [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to get the output you prefer.